# Regex python2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following list:

`['L INE', 'LI NE', 'LIN E', 'L I NE', 'L I NE', 'L I N E']`

I would like to use regex to replace every instance of the above list with 'LINE'. I used the follow expression `re.sub('^L\s+[A-Z]E$'|'^L\s+[A-Z]\s+E$', 'LINE')` but I'm getting incorrect results.

I'm hoping any good soul can give me a nice expression that can tackle all the cases above, and also point me to a good and simple regex source that I can follow to learn more about it as I'm very new to using it. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=['L INE', 'LI NE', 'LIN E', 'L I NE', 'L I NE', 'L I N E']
#loop through each item in list
for i in range(len(lst)):
  #\s means 0 or more whitespaces
  lst[i]=re.sub('^L\s*I\s*N\s*E$','LINE',lst[i]) 
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import re
 a=['L INE', 'LI NE', 'LIN E', 'L I NE', 'L I NE', 'L I N E']
 for b in a: 
    print(re.sub('L\\s*I\\s*N\\s*E', 'LINE', b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for too much and/or too little stuff: `^L\s+[A-Z]E$` would match "L [any *single* capital letter]E", like "L XE" for example. But `\s+` requires *one or more* whitespace characters so it would skip "LXE."

Since the whitespace could appear between any character, you could make a regex that searches for zero or more whitespace characters (`\s`) between every character you know you need to match. So:

`^(l|L)\s*(i|I)\s*(n|N)\s*(e|E)\s*$`

would match the items in your list.

A simpler and more understandable approach would be to use `replace()` on all the strings. This should be faster than compiling and matching on a regex.

If you know they will all be upper case for instance:

```
myList = ['L INE', 'LI NE', 'LIN E', 'L I NE', 'L I NE', 'L I N E']
# this iterates over your original list and makes a new list that 
# is composed of just the items with whitespace removed
cleanedList = [item.replace(" ","") for item in myList]
# print it and see!
print cleanedList
```

You can get more complex too if there are other patterns you need to escape, or if you need to set conditions on when you maybe *don't* want to remove whitespace.

I really recommend diving into regexes since they are super helpful, but in Python there's often a simpler way to do it! Try searching for online regex testers for one of the many interactive regex tools. They are super helpful. [Here's](https://regex101.com/) a good one: https://regex101.com/

Comment: PS - what does this have to do with anything in your post title?